# Magento 2 - how to change sorting by ID to sorting by name in custom grid column which has values as names from another collection

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have a custom grid which has **parent_company_id** stored in its table, and in the grid list I have displayed **parent_company_name** by using join the current table with company table using the ID.

When I click on the **parent_company_id** grid column, it is sorting the values based on ID in ascending and descending order.
[Please see the image for better clarification, Here the word starting with D comes before A because it is sorting by ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbBoe.png)

```
<column name="parent_company_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Test\Test1\Model\Source\Subcompany\ParentCompanyList</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Company Name</item>                    
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

> Test\Test1\Model\Source\Subcompany\ParentCompanyList.php

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $activeCompanyList = $this->helper->getAllCompany();
        $ListOptions[] = [
            'value' => "",
            'label' => 'Please Select'
        ];
        foreach ($activeCompanyList as $list) {
            $ListOptions[] = [
                'value' => $list['id'],
                'label' => $list['name']
            ];
        }
        return $ListOptions;
    }
```

I have tried to join the table in Collection. But its not worked.

```
protected function _initSelect()
     {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->company_table = $this->getTable("tbl_company");
        $this->getSelect()
            ->join(array('company' =>$this->company_table), $this->main_table . 'parent_company_id= company.id',
            array('*')
        );
```

Also tried giving name instead of id as value in the toOptionArray(). doesnot worked because the array then become associate array,

Any idea how can I sort by alphabetical order here?

Thank you.